# Who was the enemy of Spider-Man who acquired his powers and said "Where were these powers when I was in High School"?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, spider-man

About a decade ago, I saw in a Marvel encyclopedia-style book a frame from an issue of one of the Spider-Man series. In it, an enemy had pretty much defeated Peter Parker using the same powers as his. He was quoted saying:

> Where were these powers when I was in High School?

Peter responded in his thoughts, reflecting:

> Inside someone who could control them. Inside me.

After much research I still cannot find who the enemy was. Who was he and what storyline arc was it?

Comment: I'll hazard a guess, but won't answer due to a lack of a confirmed quote: Eddie Brock. As Venom, Eddie had all of Spidey's abilities and more.

Comment: Brock-Venom would be my guess as well, as to my knowledge Venom's the only character other than good ol' Spidey himself to have his same powers.

Comment: I did think of Venom as well, but I've done extensive Googling and I simply can't find the storyline or artwork that corresponds to what I remember. I agree though that Venom is the most likely candidate for this. Hopefully someone will be able to confirm.

It's a shame really because I remember that panel being one of the most brilliantly done panels I've ever seen in all my comic collecting, and I'm desperate to get either the issue or the whole TPB.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the encyclopedia instead? If you can find a copy of that you'll be set.

Comment: Another potential is Carnage - he and Venom are pretty much the shortlist of villains with powers identical to Spidey.

Comment: Could it be Ezekiel?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezekiel_(comics)#Powers_and_abilities

He is of advanced age

Comment: Or Arachne? She got her powers when in college
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Carpenter

Comment: Ezekiel and Arachne aren't the ones I think. They both don't seem to have almost killed Spidey in an act of pure savagery as the comic I read implies.

Carnage/Venom are the most likely I admit, and that possibly their hosts were the ones to say the lines I quoted. It's still very much an open question though.

Comment: I don't think this is Venom or Carnage.  I'm pretty sure this quote is from when Doc Ock took over Spidey's body, but I can't find the scans at the moment.

Comment: @MartianInvader - Can you recall which book it’s from?

Comment: I recall reading this.. but I'm pretty sure it was when Peter got leeched by Morbius or someone else? If it comes to me I'll answer

Comment: It’s not Carl King, aka The Thousand, is it? The issues he’s in don’t have quite the dialogue you mention but there is a similar theme there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Presumably, the character you're looking for is River Verys, AKA **[Tendril](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/River_Verys_(Earth-616))**, an obscure villain who appeared in the four-part *[Spider-Man: The Final Adventure](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_The_Final_Adventure_Vol_1)* miniseries in the mid '90s, and that's about it in terms of actual stories.

The dialogue you mentioned appears during a fight between him and Spider-Man in the [fourth issue](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_The_Final_Adventure_Vol_1_4) of that series.

> TENDRIL: I gotta tell you, bud--knowing I can kill anyone I really want to is a total rush! I mean, where were these powers when I was in high school?
>
> SPIDER-MAN: Where they belonged. Inside of someone who could control them. Me.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: The Final Adventure #4* (March, 1996)</sub>

I'm not sure which encyclopedia-style book you might've seen that panel in. I checked the following...

- *[Spider-Man Unmasked](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_Unmasked_Vol_1_1)* (November, 1996)
- *[Marvel Encyclopedia Vol. 1 Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Encyclopedia_Vol_1_Spider-Man)* (October, 2003)
- *[Spider-Man: Back in Black Handbook](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_Back_in_Black_Handbook_Vol_1_1)* (March, 2007)
- *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #12](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_12)* (January, 2010)

... and while Tendril has entries in each of those, I didn't see that panel in any of them. I also checked *[Spider-Man The Ultimate Guide](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man_The_Ultimate_Guide_Vol_1_1)* (February, 2001), but Tendril isn't mentioned or shown in that.

Comment: This is the one! Thank you!